# table background clear - objective c - cocoa

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, cocoa-touch, uikit

Hi I want to display my table view without any background color so I used the following code to clear it

```
[uiTableView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```

This worked fine in the new iPad and also other generation iPads except it failed to work in iPad version one. The table shows with the background gray color. Is this something to do with iOS 5 ? Can anyone let me know if we can clear the background color in first version iPads.

Comment: have you tried to to set `[uiTableView setOpaque:NO]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have noticed the same thing under iOS 5+. Try this:

```
[uiTableView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[uiTableView setBackgroundView:nil];
```

Should work as intended.

EDIT: If you're using the default cells, they cover the `UITableView`, so changing the `UITableView`'s background color and view doesn't do anything. Try this in your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method:

```
cellName.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
cellName.backgroundView = nil;
```

Comment: It didn't work. The iPad one iOS5 seems to be totally insensitive to anything related to background color. Even if I change the background color to someother color it isn't changing to the color specified. –

Comment: Are you using custom UITableView cells? Also, is `uiTableView` an instance variable? These are not class methods.

Comment: I am not using custom UITableView cells.. Yes uiTableView is an instance variable

Comment: If you're not using custom cells, and are using `UITableViewPlain`, than the whole `UITableView` is covered with cells, which is why changing the background color of the table view doesn't do anything. You'd need to change the UITableViewCell background color. I'll update my answer.

Comment: That didn't work either but when I added                                               [tableView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [tableView setBackgroundView:nil]; in the tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath method it started working.

Comment: I *really* don't know why it wouldn't work there. Since it works in the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` it seems to me that the instance variable somehow isn't connected well to the table view. Maybe a broken connection to IB? Really odd.

Comment: My bad ... I didn't do the synthesize for the instance variable. Sorry for the confusion. Your way works now. Many thanks!.

Comment: Glad we could sort it out! Happy coding! :)

Answer (score 0):

As tableview has one more view as its background. You can set the backgroundColor in two ways.

i) Set the background color for the tableview and set the backgroundView to nil.

```
[uiTableView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[uiTableView setBackgroundView:nil];
```

ii)  Set the backgroundColor for the tableView backgroundView.

```
UIColor *backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
uiTableView.backgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.tableView.bounds];
uiTableView.backgroundView.backgroundColor = backgroundColor;
```

Comment: Both the ways didn't work. The iPad one iOS5 seems to be totally insensitive to anything related to background color. Even if I change the background color to someother color it isn't changing to the color specified.